# Reshape matrix from .txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function

I have this code that takes an `.txt` that has integers in the following format:

```
3 7 12  90 11
4   87  103 1 15 23 72 3
8   2
10
65 34 18 29
```

I would like to write a function that reshapes it into a matrix by the size prompted by the user and it the matrix size given is bigger that the number of elements, it would return with a message.

but I'm unable to enter the integers of the file, or I don't know how

for example:

If you attempt to reshape it to a 4 by 6 matrix, you should get a message like:

```
Cannot reshape matrix: not enough matrix elements
```

and leaves the file as is.

The new content of the file, reshaped to a 3 by 6 matrix, would be:

```
size 4 by 6
 
3712 9011
4 87 10311523723 82
10
65 34 18 29
  
3 7 12 90 11 4 
87 103 1 15 23 72 
3 8 2 10 65 34
#the numbers would be separated by "\t"
```

so far all I have is this and I'm stuck. I cannot use imports like Numpy.

```
def reshape (nCols, nRows, file):
    matrixSize = int(nCols*nRows)
    count = 0
    matrix = []
    total_numbers = 0
    for line in file :
        parts = line.split()
        total_numbers += len(parts)
    if matrixSize > total_numbers:
        return print("Not enough elements in the matrix")
    else:
        for i in range(0, nRows):
            while len(matrix)> 0: matrix.pop()
            for i in range(count, count+nCols):
                matrix.append(i)
                count+=1
            print(matrix)




getColInteger= int(input("Enter column integer size: "))
getRowsInteger = input("Enter rows integer size: ")
openFile = open("mat.txt", "r+")
toGetReshape = reshape(getColInteger, getRowsInteger, openFile)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create one list with all numbers and add each number in matrix.

check below code:

```
def reshape (nCols, nRows, file):
    matrixSize = int(nCols*nRows)
    count = 0
    matrix = []
    numbers = []
    numbers = []
    [numbers.extend(line.strip().split()) for line in file]
    total_numbers = len(numbers)
    if matrixSize > total_numbers:
        return print("Not enough elements in the matrix")
    else:
        for i in range(0, nRows):
            while len(matrix)> 0: matrix.pop()
            for i in range(count, count+nCols):
                matrix.append(numbers[i])
                count+=1
            print(matrix)

getColInteger= int(input("Enter column integer size: "))
getRowsInteger = int(input("Enter rows integer size: "))
openFile = open("test.txt", "r+")
toGetReshape = reshape(getColInteger, getRowsInteger, openFile)
```